# How to disable exit full screen popup in virt-manager

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I'm using `virt-manager` with kvm, however I've found that in fullscreen mode (with spice), the exit fullscreen popup gets in my way often.

[image]

Is there a way to disable this popup from showing whenever I move my mouse near it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access VMs using `virt-viewer` instead - it has kiosk mode:

```
virt-viewer --kiosk ${YOUR_VM_NAME}
```

The only way to exit kiosk mode I know is to run another virt-viewer (in a separate terminal) again without `--kiosk` option (this will drop connection for the first one) and then you will be able to press `<Ctrl> + <C>` for the first one to close its windows.

Additional benefit of `virt-viewer` instad of `virt-manager` is the ability to open all displays (for example, if your VM has several Video QXL devices, separate window will be opened for each device).